# No text shown in JTextArea upon event

Tags: java, swing

I am unsure in how to fix this bug I have. It runs fine with no errors when I use it, but no input shows when i click one of the buttons.
I am using eclipse with JDK 1.7.1, and Windows 7.
Code is basically creating 3 buttons with a TextArea that displays the input of each button when clicked.

```
public class Main implements ActionListener{

public JTextArea text;
public JButton b1;
public JButton b2;
public JButton b3;
public String choices[] = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main gui = new Main();
    gui.go();
}

public void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rock Paper Scissors");
    text = new JTextArea(13,20);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JButton b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
    JButton b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
    JButton b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    text.setEditable(false);


    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(text);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    panel1.add(scroller);
    panel2.add(b1);
    panel2.add(b2);
    panel2.add(b3);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel2);
    frame.setSize(350,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (e.getSource() == b1) {
         text.setText("Your choice was" + choices[0]);
            }
     if (e.getSource() == b2) {
         text.setText("Your choice was" + choices[1]);
            }
     if (e.getSource() == b3) {
         text.setText("Your choice was" + choices[2]);
            }


}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're never initializing the instance variables b1, b2, and b3. So the equals operator won't work, because the instance variables are still null. I would recommend that in your go() method, you don't create new local variables b1, b2 and b3, but instead initialize the instance variables. I changed your code:

```
public void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rock Paper Scissors");
    text = new JTextArea(13,20);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
    b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
    b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    text.setEditable(false);


    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(text);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    panel1.add(scroller);
    panel2.add(b1);
    panel2.add(b2);
    panel2.add(b3);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel2);
    frame.setSize(350,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

Comment: Just to clarify if it's not obvious, declaring `JButton b1` within the method as a local variable hides `b1` as an instance variable.

Comment: Yes exactly. I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating local variables which shadow the instance variables:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
JButton b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
JButton b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
JButton b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
JButton b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
```

This is declaring three new *local* variables which are shadowing your instance variables, rather than assigning values to the existing variables. Therefore the instance variables stay as null, and your checks like this:

```
if (e.getSource() == b1)
```

will never evaluate to true.

Simply change those lines to:

```
b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
```

I've tried this (after adding the various imports) and it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
JButton b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
JButton b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
JButton b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
```

inside your function, you define these variables inside the current method scrope, and therefore your program will work as intended if you remove the definition before the variables making it

```
b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that this code will work 100% even though I haven't tested it:

```
public class Main implements ActionListener{

public JTextArea text;
public JButton b1;
public JButton b2;
public JButton b3;
public String choices[] = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main gui = new Main();
    gui.go();
}
public void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rock Paper Scissors");
    text = new JTextArea(13,20);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    b1 = new JButton(choices[0]);
    b2 = new JButton(choices[1]);
    b3 = new JButton(choices[2]);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    text.setEditable(false);


    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(text);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    panel1.add(scroller);
    panel2.add(b1);
    panel2.add(b2);
    panel2.add(b3);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel2);
    frame.setSize(350,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (e.getSource().equals(b1)) {
         text.setText("Your choice was" + choices[0]);
            }
     if (e.getSource().equals(b2)) {
         text.setText("Your choice was" + choices[1]);
            }
     if (e.getSource().equals(b3)) {
         text.setText("Your choice was" + choices[2]);
            }


}
}
```